# Saving data to store VUEX

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Morning all,

I am new to Vuex and am trying to start with the basics. 
I have followed the tutorials for setting up a "todo list" and got all that working. But I also want more of a generic store for authentication.

Essentially, I want the current logged in users information to be stored within the Vuex store.
I currently have this code below withing app.vue

```js
created () {
  this.fetchProjects()
  console.log('console-test ' + this.$store.getters.allProjects[0])

  // Firebase Auth
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      this.user = user

      const ref = db.collection('Users')
        .where('user_id', '==', this.user.uid)
      ref.get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          this.userInfo = doc.data()
        })
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('user auth = ' + this.user.uid)
        console.log('user auth = ' + this.user.email)
        console.log('user info = ' + this.userInfo.username)
      })
    } else {
      this.user = null
    }
  })
}
```

The area where I am console logging, I am thinking it would be a good idea to push the information currently stored in data via "this.user" to vuex store, to easily use throughout the app. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you already know how to use Vuex to store data in a todo app, there is nothing different about storing user data. Vuex just works with data, period. So you can either commit a mutation or dispatch an action and pass along your data.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you must store user data into the store, and also store data into browser's `localStorage` to persist user data on refresh. Big frameworks like `NuxtJs` are working this way.

```
 .then(() => {
        console.log('user auth = ' + this.user.uid)

        this.$store.dispatch('storeJustLoggedInUser', this.user.uid);
 })
```

In your vuex store:

```
actions: {
    storeJustLoggedInUser({commit, state}, uid){
          commit('STORE_USER_UID', uid)
   }
}
```

This is just a pseudo code, hopefully you get the idea!